# In Lotto what is the minimum number of tickets you would need to buy to guarantee at least one 3 number match?

Tags: probability

In Lotto (the UK lottery), you pick 6 numbers from a pool of 49. How many tickets would you need to guarantee at least one match of 3 numbers?

Wikipedia shows the probability of matching 3 numbers at 55:1. Does that mean if you buy 55 tickets you are guaranteed to get at least one match?

(P.S. I did search here and find another lottery question, possibly asking the same thing - but obviously didn't understand that.)

cheers

Comment: Should we add the [combinatorics] tag?

Comment: @cardinal: At least that would be more appropriate than probability, since the question does not involve any probabilities.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Believe it or not, this is an open problem. Up to the present time, despite advanced mathematics and supercomputers, the precise minimum is unknown. It *is* known that the minimum value (called $L(49,6,6,3)$ in mathematical terminology) lies between $87$ and $163$. There is more information on this topic [here](http://www.cs.umanitoba.ca/~vanrees/revlottodesign.pdf).

[Here](http://lottery.merseyworld.com/Wheel/Wheel.html) is a set of $163$ ticket choices that works. Maybe a smaller set could be found to guarantee 3 winning numbers, but nobody knows this for sure.