# How many sets of all possible number pairs with each set having 6 numbers from 1-10 , what am I doing wrong?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

My Understanding

$n$= numbers to choose between $1$-$n$ i.e. 10

$r$ = match count i.e. 2

$q$ = count of numbers allowed to choose in 1 seti.e. 6

*Note : While choosing a set, numbers cant be repeated and order doesn't matter. After each set all numbers are put back to choose next set.*

possible combinations $r$ numbers at a time out of $n$ numbers  $c_{total}=  C(n,r)$

possible combinations $r$ numbers in 1 set (has $q$ numbers)$c_{set-total} =  C(q,r)$

since each set already has $C(q,r)$
total number of sets $S =c_{total}/c_{total} = C(n,r)/C(q,r)$  **Is this even correct ?**

In fact sometime back I was able to logically conclude $S < c_{total}/c_{total} = C(n,r)/C(q,r)$ but now I am completely blacked out.

by using this for the said values  $n=10, r=2, q=6$

then $c_{total}=45 ,c_{set-total}=15$

there for $S=3$

In $3$ sets I should get all possible pair of number between $1-10$

I stumbled upon  [La Jolla Covering Repository](https://ljcr.dmgordon.org/cover/show_cover.php?v=10&k=6&t=2)  which says it is $4$ .

What am I doing wrong? Also how do I generate these sets with values, is there a logic?

Similar Question: [Guaranteed to guess two numbers in one from twelve lottery tickets, if falls 6 balls with numbers from 1 to 36](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3275966/guaranteed-to-guess-two-numbers-in-one-from-twelve-lottery-tickets-if-falls-6)